# One-To-Many Count

Tags: nhibernate, one-to-many

I wonder if this can be resolved with less overhead:
Given a simple one-to-many relationship Product --> Size (Product has got one size). In order to figure out how many products are assigned to a size I would update the mapping of Size with a Product-`Bag`. But what if I am only interested in the count (no need for any product details), can this be done without the overhead of loading all the product-objects?

Thx for any tipps
sl3dg3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use attribute `lazy="extra"` in hbm or `ExtraLazyLoad()` in fluent mappings for Product collection. 
With extra lazy loading Products.Count translates into sql 'select count'

See [corresponding question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079962/nhibernate-lazy-extra)

Answer (score -1):

Why not create a query? Something like this for Linq (of course HQL, criteria or QueryOver should work too):

```
int count = session.Query<Product>()
    .Where(x => x.Size != null)
    .Count();
```