# prevent unnecessary cross joins in count query of generated sql code

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I am using this query:

```
return from oi in NHibernateSession.Current.Query<BlaInteraction>()
select new BlaViewModel
{
  ...

  NoPublications = oi.Publications.Count(), 

  ...
};
```

BlaInteraction contains an IList of publications (i.e. entities). To determine the number of publications one does not really need to do all the joins for a publication. Can I prevent nhibernate from using joins in the generated sql (e.g. using projection???) somehow?

Thanks.

Christian

PS:

This is what NH produces (slightly adapted):

```
select cast(count(*) as INT) from RelationshipStatementPublications publicatio21_, Publication publicatio22_ inner join Statements publicatio22_1_ on publicatio22_.StatementId=publicatio22_1_.DBId where publicatio21_.StatementId = 22762181 and publicatio21_.PublicationId=publicatio22_.StatementId
```

This is what would be sufficient:

```
select cast(count(*) as INT) from RelationshipStatementPublications publicatio21_ where publicatio21_.StatementId = 22762181
```

Comment: Do you know that it *is* hydrating publications? What does SQL Profiler say is actually being run on the server?

Comment: Thanks - sorry you are right. The joins have nothing to do with 'hydration'. I have edited the question and added some sql.

Comment: (not an nhibernate expert) the fact that it generates an implciti `CROSS JOIN` (tables in the `FROM` clause that are not explicitly joined) suggests NHibernate lacks some piece of knowledge about the relationships between objects; however, I would first want to check the SQL execution plans of its query and the ideal query - it may be that *SQL Server* is able to work out the easy thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the best solution I have found so far is to use a FNH Formula:

```
mapping.Map(x => x.NOPublications).Formula("(select count(distinct RelationshipStatementPublications.PublicationId) from RelationshipStatementPublications where RelationshipStatementPublications.StatementId = DBId)");

public virtual int NOPublications {get; private set;}
```

when I map from the domain to the view model I use:

```
NoPublications = oi.NOPublications,
```

Christian

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you just create another query ?

```
Session.QueryOver<Publication>().Where(x => x.BlaInteractionId == idSentAsParameter).Select(Projections.RowCount()).SingleOrDefault<int>();
```

I think that's will work

```
return from oi in NHibernateSession.Current.Query<BlaInteraction>()
select new BlaViewModel
{
  ...
  NoPublications = Session.QueryOver<Publication>().Where(x => x.BlaInteractionId == oi.Id).Select(Projections.RowCount()).SingleOrDefault<int>();

  ...
};
```

Another edit, have you tried [lazy="extra"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079962/nhibernate-lazy-extra) ?

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate this? I have a class BlaInteraction which contains an IList<Publication>. My query maps certain properties of BlaInteraction to the view model and counts the number of publications of each BlaInteraction (TOP n). The reason for my appraoch is that I want to make full use of telerik's 'Linq-based expression engine' which generates all the 'stuff' for filtering, paging and sorting.

Comment: Added another example, check if its ok

Comment: This does not work and I tried this before you posted it. The things is BlaInteraction is derived from statement. any statement has Ilist<publication> which is mapped using mapping.HasManyToMany(x =>
x.Publications).Table("RelationshipStatementPublications"); and i also have a dedicated RelationshipStatementPublications entity. so something like this should work: NoPublications = NHibernateSession.Current.QueryOver<RelationshipStatementPublication>().Where(x => x.Statement.Id == oi.Id).Select(Projections.RowCount()).SingleOrDefault<int>(),
but i get a path exception.

Comment: please also have a look here: http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/d78756291f46e3e6 Thanks.